# How can I calculate field strength of a Neodymium Ring magnet at an angle?

Tags: magnets

How can I calculate field strength of a Neodymium Ring magnet at an angle?
I have a Neodymium Ring magnet, and I rotate the magnet around an axis perpendicular to the poles. (Not continuous rotation). For a given distance from the surface, and or for a given angle away from the center of the field, how can I calculate the field strength?

I have looked at some methods to calculate field strength, but they refer to electro-magnets, and current. Where this is a rare earth magnet, I am unsure how to perform such calculations.

The application is a device that exerts a magnetic field into a device, where either a weak, or non-existent field is not already present.

Comment: Get a hallotron chip, attach it to a power source and a multimeter, and measure that field. With a shape as complex as a ring magnet, you'll get totally bogged down in the calculations and get nowhere because you won't have accurate parameters of the magnet to begin with.